# Problem operating 74HCT4066 with Arduino providing logical states as enable pin

Tags: arduino

I made the necessary connections such as following ;

```
14 - Vcc
 7 - Gnd
 1 -  A7
 2 - Vcc 
13 -   6
```

and the following is the code ;

```
const int analog_value_Z = A7;
const int enable = 7;

void setup() {  
pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
digitalWrite(enable,HIGH);
Serial.print(analogRead(analog_value_Z));
Serial.print("\n");
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(enable,LOW);
Serial.print(analogRead(analog_value_Z));
Serial.print("\n");
delay(1000);
}
```

Since pin1 of switch is directly connected to analog read pin and the other pin is connected to  Vcc, I am trying to switch between ON/OFF states by applying HIGH/LOW to enable pin. I expect result such as ;

```
1023
   0
1023
   0
   .
   .
   .
```

Instead I get :

```
1023
1023
1023
   .
   .
```

What am I doing wrong ? This IC opens and closes the switch between Y and Z pins of it with the change in enable pin. Please provide some guidance.

Comment: You're saying that you have the enable line (pin 13 on the 74hct4066) connected to digital I/O pin 6 of the Arduiino, but your code is using pin 7.

Comment: Also, when the switch is open, A7 is just floating. You really should have this switch go from Vcc to ground through a resistor (a load), then check the voltage at the resistor. E.g., Tie 74hct4066 pin 1 to Vcc, tie 74hct4066 pin 2 to a 1k resistor and connect the other end of the resistor to ground. Also tie pin 2 to your A7 input.  When the switch closes, A7 should be Vcc. When the switch is open, A7 should be ground.